# Resizing page for mobile

Tags: html, css, magento

I'm a bit of an HTML novice, but I've been tasked with creating a landing page for a client of ours.

I've been working on this for weeks (don't laugh). I know it'd take a seasoned web developer minutes to make, but I'm really struggling here at this point.

I've managed to get the page laid out like the PSD that I originally created (me and my big mouth designed it in Photoshop, and now my boss wants me to create it in HTML...) but I can't get it to behave as it should do on mobile.

For the MOST part it works ok-ish in Chrome on desktop (seems to not work so well in Safari though).

My brain is melted at this point, can anyone help?

Link to what it's supposed to look like on desktop: http://jwemploymentlaw.co.uk/magento/media/V3_LandingPage_CastIronBaths_noborder.jpg

On mobile it needs to stack the images one under each other, or maybe 2 side by side? At this point, I can't even begin to fathom how to do either.

Code:

```
<div class="std"><div>&nbsp;</div>
<div style="background: #d5d5d5; padding-top: 20px;">
<h2 style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: #333333; font-size: xx-large; font-size: 3vw; font-family: Open Sans;">Antique Style Cast Iron Baths</span></h2>
<p style="padding-left: 10%; padding-right: 10%; padding-bottom: 25px;">
<span style="font-family: Open Sans; color: #333333; font-size: medium; font-size: 1.5vw; font-weight: 50;">Our baths have been manufactured from cast iron for decades, with porcelain enamel fused on to the casting at high temperatures to give a gloss surface which is highly resistant to scratching and staining. The superior exterior finish is smoothed and primed ready for painting in your choice of colour. When you buy your cast iron bath from Aston Matthews you are investing in the highest quality product from the originator of the design, at the best possible price.</span></p>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>



<div style="float: left; width: 100%; align-content: center; margin-left: 0%; margin-right: 0%;">
<div style="display: inline-block;">
<div class="col" style="width: 25%; float: left; text-align: center;"><img style="text-align: center; max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto\9; display: inline-block;" alt="test" src="http://jwemploymentlaw.co.uk/magento/media/resident_logo.png" /></div>
<div class="col" style="width: 50%; float: left; font-size: medium; text-align: center; display: inline-block;">
<p style="text-align: center; font-family: Open Sans; color: #333333; font-size: 1.25vw"><em>"Excellent one-to-one service, lovely staff, always there to help"</em></p>
<p style="text-align: center; font-family: Open Sans; color: #333333; font-size: 1.25vw"><em>"Right from the beginning Steve Cook at Aston Matthews was proactive with ideas around our design concept"</em></p>
<p style="text-align: center; font-family: Open Sans; color: #333333; font-size: 1.25vw"><em>"The staff at Aston Matthews were extremely helpful when I was planning my bathroom refurbishment"</em></p>
</div>
<div class="col" style="width: 25%; float: left; text-align: center;"><img style="text-align: center; max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto\9; display: inline-block;" alt="test" src="http://jwemploymentlaw.co.uk/magento/media/houzz_logo.png" /></div>
</div></div>



<div class="container" style="padding-top: 20px; align: center; float: left">

<div class="container-two" style="position: relative; z-index: 1; top: 10px; float: left;">
<div style="background: #3d88a8; width: 100%; height: 175px; text-align: center; padding-top: 0px; z-index: -1; position: relative;">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 25px; font-size: 2.5vw; font-family: Open Sans; color: #ffffff; position: absolute; top: 20%; left: 100px; right: 100px; font-style: normal;">Save Up To 40% On Our Bestselling Cast Iron Baths</p>
</div>

<div class="image-container" style="position: relative; left: 10px; right: 10px; float: left; text-align: center; margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; width: 100%">

<div class="row" style="float: left; text-align: center; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 0%; padding-right: 0%; width: 100%; height: auto; font-size: 1vw; position: relative; top: -90px">

<div class="col" style="position: relative; float: left; padding: 5px; width: 17%;"><img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto\9;" alt="" src="http://jwemploymentlaw.co.uk/magento/media/1.jpg" />
<div class="col" style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 5px; right: 5px; z-index: 1; background: #3d88a8; opacity: 0.80; width: auto; height: auto; padding: 5px; text-align: center; font-family: Open Sans; color: #ffffff;">
<em>Roma Clawfoot Tubs</em></div>
</div>
<div class="col" style="position: relative; float: left; padding: 5px; width: 17%;"><img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto\9;" alt="" src="http://jwemploymentlaw.co.uk/magento/media/2.jpg" />
<div class="col" style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 5px; right: 5px; z-index: 1; background: #3d88a8; opacity: 0.80; width: auto; height: auto; padding: 5px; text-align: center; font-family: Open Sans; color: #ffffff;">
<em>Luxor Clawfoot Tubs</em></div>
</div>
<div class="col" style="position: relative; float: left; padding: 5px; width: 17%;"><img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto\9;" alt="" src="http://jwemploymentlaw.co.uk/magento/media/3.jpg" />
<div class="col" style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 5px; right: 5px; z-index: 1; background: #3d88a8; opacity: 0.80; width: auto; height: auto; padding: 5px; text-align: center; font-family: Open Sans; color: #ffffff;">
<em>Rimini Bathtubs</em></div>
</div>
<div class="col" style="position: relative; float: left; padding: 5px; width: 17%;"><img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto\9;" alt="" src="http://jwemploymentlaw.co.uk/magento/media/4.jpg" />
<div class="col" style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 5px; right: 5px; z-index: 1; background: #3d88a8; opacity: 0.80; width: auto; height: auto; padding: 5px; text-align: center; font-family: Open Sans; color: #ffffff;">
<em>Verona Bathtubs</em></div>
</div>
<div class="col" style="position: relative; float: left; padding: 5px; width: 17%;"><img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto\9;" alt="" src="http://jwemploymentlaw.co.uk/magento/media/5.jpg" />
<div class="col" style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 5px; right: 5px; z-index: 1; background: #3d88a8; opacity: 0.80; width: auto; height: auto; padding: 5px; text-align: center; font-family: Open Sans; color: #ffffff;">
<em>Bateau Luxury Tubs</em></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding: 10px;">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="row" style="align: center; float: middle; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 0%; padding-right: 0%; width: 100%; font-size: 1vw; position: relative; top: -90px">
<div class="col" style="position: relative; float: left; padding: 5px; width: 17%"><img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto\9;" alt="" src="http://jwemploymentlaw.co.uk/magento/media/6.jpg" />
<div class="col" style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 5px; right: 5px; z-index: 1; background: #3d88a8; opacity: 0.80; width: auto; height: auto; padding: 5px; text-align: center; font-family: Open Sans; color: #ffffff;">
<em>Brunel Luxury Bathtubs</em></div>
</div>
<div class="col" style="position: relative; float: left; padding: 5px; width: 17%;"><img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto\9;" alt="" src="http://jwemploymentlaw.co.uk/magento/media/7.jpg" />
<div class="col" style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 5px; right: 5px; z-index: 1; background: #3d88a8; opacity: 0.80; width: auto; height: auto; padding: 5px; text-align: center; font-family: Open Sans; color: #ffffff;">
<em>Epoca Bathtubs</em></div>
</div>
<div class="col" style="position: relative; float: left; padding: 5px; width: 17%;"><img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto\9;" alt="" src="http://jwemploymentlaw.co.uk/magento/media/8.jpg" />
<div class="col" style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 5px; right: 5px; z-index: 1; background: #3d88a8; opacity: 0.80; width: auto; height: auto; padding: 5px; text-align: center; font-family: Open Sans; color: #ffffff;">
<em>Novara Built-In Tubs</em></div>
</div>
<div class="col" style="position: relative; float: left; padding: 5px; width: 17%;"><img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto\9;" alt="" src="http://jwemploymentlaw.co.uk/magento/media/9.jpg" />
<div class="col" style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 5px; right: 5px; z-index: 1; background: #3d88a8; opacity: 0.80; width: auto; height: auto; padding: 5px; text-align: center; font-family: Open Sans; color: #ffffff;">
<em>Slipper Soaking Tubs</em></div>
</div>
<div class="col" style="position: relative; float: left; padding: 5px; width: 17%;"><img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; width: auto\9;" alt="" src="http://jwemploymentlaw.co.uk/magento/media/10.jpg" />
<div class="col" style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 5px; right: 5px; z-index: 1; background: #3d88a8; opacity: 0.80; width: auto; height: auto; padding: 5px; text-align: center; font-family: Open Sans; color: #ffffff;">
<em>Hanover Bathtubs</em></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have a few unclosed </div>

Comment: Thanks, I've been through and closed them, but it's still causing the same problems.

Comment: can post ALL of the code on https://jsfiddle.net/ or on https://codepen.io/# and then post the link of the page the code is on?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m6ajn740/